# How to constrain an object to full screen

Tags: swift, view, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I want to know how to code an imageview to the full screen programmatically. Right now I know how to code an object to a specific size and position programmatically but I want to know how to get this object in the full screen no matter what device is being used.

```
FIRE.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
FIRE.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

FIRE.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
FIRE.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 700).isActive = true
FIRE.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your object is `FIRE` and the parent view is `view`. You can do it with constraints as follows.

```
FIRE.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
FIRE.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
FIRE.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
FIRE.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
FIRE.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Or you could do it using the auto-resizing mask

```
FIRE.frame = view.bounds
FIRE.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

Answer (score -1):

Goal is to set leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints of your `UIView` equal to leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints of its `superview`

---

```
FIRE.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

FIRE.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
FIRE.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
FIRE.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
FIRE.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```